# Problems on startup with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I hope this is the right place to ask, I was referred here from a topic on SO. The same topic pointed me towards using GeoServer to create maps with overlaid tracks on. I have unpacked the .war file onto my tomcat server but am getting a number of errors as listed in my catalina.out file. Having never used GeoServer before it doesn't really mean much to me at all.

Does it make sense to anyone else:

http://pastebin.com/JNkWdVER

Comment: what version of Geoserver?

Comment: 2.2.4 I believe. I downloaded start of the week from the stable section: http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Stable

Comment: The link provided is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the install is corrupt. When the war file it is deploying the jar validate is not validating on the validate jar file, which is not loading. The question is why can't it see the validate jar or why is the jar file not validating.

I would uninstall the whole stack and would re install from scratch, following the documented steps carefully, you may discover a step that was missed or was misinterpreted. If the download was corrupt this may fix that as well.

What is your whole stack? Just geoserver? What is the purpose of your application? just a few questions that might help clarify the correct path. If you just want to overlay tracks you could use qgis and if they are from a gps do a conversion from nmea to gpx to shapefile and add as a layer. Cetus gps or waypoint plus, gps babel, and trackmaker are handy to play with for tracking and data conversion.